# How to render cross section area between a 3d model and a plane in libgdx?

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I have set up a 3d scene with a model and a plane following xoppa's tutorial [here](http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/). I set plane opacity to 0.5f and has the result as in the left picture but I want to show the cut section shaded as in right picture. How can I do this? Thank you very much.
[image]

Edited: I haved tried set the the model opacity to 0.5f as Tanmay Patil suggested but still the result is like the left image.

Answer (score 0):

The parts that you are trying to render are definitely **inside** the 3D model.

Therefore, since you wish them to be seen, the first obvious thing that would come to mind is having some transparency for the 3D model as well.

If you make both plane and the model semi-transparent, the portion you are asking would definitely be visible. But if you wish to render it differently this method won't work. If you just want it to be seen (any way possible) you should be good to go.

Good luck.

Comment: I am not sure if setting the opacity of the `Model` to 0.5f helps, cause the `Face`s inside the `Model`s are culled (backfaceculling), so they won't blend over each other. @user1876292 Try to disable `backfaceCulling`.